# 2 Mice, capturing exclusively one mouse on windows (DirectInput, DDK, Linux, anything)

Tags: windows, mouse, driver, wdk, directinput

I have connected 2 mice to PC and I wish one mouse to work as regular mouse and capture second mouse exclusively.

First I was trying DirectInput. It showed 2 devices with word mouse in InstanceName.
But only one device had DeviceType.Mouse and it was only really working device.
When I was acquiring it was blocking both mice.

Second I decided to create driver. I downloaded WinDDK. There is Mouse Filter driver sample.
I was able to compile it.
But I am not driver programmer. It is complex for me to understand but it has some code related to PS/2 mouse. All my mice are USB.

It should be installed with .INF file. I prefer it be dynamically loaded.

I am not quite sure that it is right direction. 
I do it for my hobbyist robotic project. I wish PC take some information from mouse as sensor.
I think there must be existing similar projects or solutions.

I have linux pc on my table as well. May be better to attach mouse to linux and parse

```
/dev/input/mouse0
/dev/input/mouse1
/dev/input/mouse2
```

looks like 
sudo cat /dev/input/mouse1 - gives some data but does not block device from clicks and movements.

I hope simple solution already exists

Cheers
Max

Comment: How are you going to handle 2 different mouse pointers? What happens when you move the second mouse?

Comment: It should not move pointer but my application must receive information about mouse movement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Linux, you need to either declare the first mouse as the `CorePointer` or configure the second mouse to have `SendCoreEvents` false. See the `xorg.conf(5)` man page for more details.

Comment: I have set option autoadddevices false. I lost touchpad on laptop that I rarely use and I have one working mouse and one mouse that I can share over network now. Thanks You!

Comment: I can't make 2 mice (USB+touch) work and 1 blocked. I tried many combinations and not luck or all 3 work or only 1.