# Single-touch screen interfering with mouse main cursor

Tags: winapi

I have a touch screen that is handled as a mouse in windows.
I'm trying to figure out how can retrieve the position of my click in the signle-touch screen without making the main cursor moves. Something like this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4419947/5284178) but for windows.

I can retrieve the position of the click in the touchscreen using `GetRawInputData` and now i want to capture the event or block it in order to not mess up with the main cursor.

Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

When touch messages are not handled they are translated into standard mouse messages. 
So handle all the touch messages and the mouse cursor should not be influenced.

Comment: This is not true. Handling `WM_TOUCH` messages does not prevent the system from updating the mouse cursor position.